# Controladores Codeigniter 4 no funcionan bien!

Tags: codeigniter

Buen dia gente!!!
tengo el siguiente problema.
Todos mis controladores en codeigniter 4 me redireccionan a localhost/dashboard que es la pagina principal de xampp.

Estoy con Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Agrega más detalles a tu pregunta: es difícil ayudar sin tener mucho contexto. Lee [ask].

Answer (score 0):

te aconsejo que pruebas en verificar las configuraciones de la base url y también las de tu archivo .env
tienes que configurar estas rutas de la siguiente manera:
En la base url. apuntar al host y el proyecto y en la env a todo en general
te muestro:

app
public $baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080';

ENV

'http://localhost:8080/sistema-gestion-de-casos/public/index.php';